# Deployed an ASP.NET App to AWS Elastic BeanStalk what is the url?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I deployed a simple ASP.NET application to AWS Elastic BeanStalk.  From where do I get the URL of the deployed application?  I clicked on the title next to the application and it takes me to a standard welcome page.

Plus how do I create the package for the application? is it just a case of zipping up the file? and how does AWS know to extract (what if I put two projects into the zip)?

Comment: How did you publish? from aws toolkit for VS?

Comment: I went to the site and uploaded the document, the AWS toolkit seems to be broken in VS 2015.

Comment: Fortunately, for me it is working perfectly.But regardless of how you publish, you can always see the url from the console. Just go to services->Elastic beanstalk and select your environment and you can see the url.